# Генерация POST-запроса и его отправка

Tags: post, php

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня возникла проблема: мне надо с помощью php-скрипта сформировать POST-запрос, и отправить его на указанную страницу, с одновременным переходом на неё. По сути мне нужно имитировать всю работу HTML-формы. Прямая отправка из формы не вариант, так пхп должен обработать данные, которые вводит пользователь, внести корректировки и отправить дополненный запрос на сервер. Перечитал половину гугла. `cURL`, `file_get_contents()` не поможет, так как принимать ответ средствами php не требуется, пользователь должен перейти на страницу, куда отправляется запрос. Расчёты делать средствами JS нельзя - в итоге пользователь может подставить даже в скрытые поля формы свои значения, а также не все мобильные платформы работают с JS. Отправлять GET с помощью `header('Location: ...')` тоже нельзя, т.к. пользователь может изменить значения в адресной строке. POST с помощью `header()` отправить не получилось, хотя на форумах такой вариант описывался, но у меня он не заработал.

Вообще к чему всё это мне? Я подключаю к сайту платёжную систему. Пользователь вводит количество покупаемой игровой валюты, на сервере рассчитывается стоимость в долларах, и потом количество долларов отправляется на страницу платёжной системы, где пользователь производит оплату согласно данным, что были отправлены запросом.

Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: Все известные и надежные платежные системы обладают подробной документацией по использованию своих платежных систем. Можно, например, оплачивать товар не переходя на сайт платежных систем, а можно наоборот сформировать ссылку на сайт платежной системы(ПС) и там уже производить оплату. В таком случае вы настраиваете ПС чтобы она при успешной или не успешной попытке возвращала на определенный УРЛ ответ, где хранилась бы информация  о статусе. При этом все это шифруется с помощью цифровых подписей. Это просто в 2-х словах на деле же там есть нюансы. В общем читайте информацию от ПС.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко Спасибо за ответи, но в том-то и дело, что я прочитал доки по своей ПС. И мне не нужна оплата товара не переходя на сайт ПС. Мне как раз-таки нужен переход на сайт ПС. Просто перед переходом мне нужно немного изменить POST-запрос. Вся проблема именно в этом. :(

Comment: Что за таинственная ПС и каков сценарий дописки данных перед отправкой?

Comment: ПС - Интеркасса 2.0. Просто в первой версии у них была конвертация валют. Можно было указать количество игровой валюты, в настройках кассы указать курс, по которому она будет конвертироваться в USD, и на странице оплаты уже выводилась стоимость в USD. Я же пользуюсь второй версией (старая ими не поддерживается), а она ещё не весь функционал поддерживает. :(
Вот мне и приходится конвертировать игровую валюту в USD у себя на сервере и на ПС отправлять уже стоимость оплаты в USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта точно, как вы хотите — не существует.

Начнём с конца: сервер ПС получает HTTP POST запрос от клиента и отдаёт ему страницу в ответ. Клиент в этом случае - браузер вашего пользователя, десктоп с JS или мобильный без JS.

В этот диалог двух сторон вы со своим php можете вмешаться только как Mim (man in the middle) – т.е. поднять прокси и трафик пускать через себя - не пройдет из-за https и сертификатов ПС.

Либо вы должны сообщить на клиент заранее ваши изменённые данные, и тот вправе их как угодно модифицировать и подделывать, прежде чем отправить в ПС. Тоже не вариант.

В это же время все рабочие сценарии прикрутки ПС ими обычно уже продуманы, и на каждый имеются надёжные решения, описанные в документации.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. В общем, по видимому, придётся ждать, когда ПС сделает у себя конвертацию валюты, а пока что довольствоваться открытым GET-запросом. :(
В принципе, если хорошо продумать систему оплаты, то даже при открытом запросе пользователь получит столько игровой валюты, сколько он оплатил в действительности (даже если подставит свою сумму). Уже делаю именно так - окончательное кол-во игровой валюты будет рассчитываться уже после оплаты.
---
Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Можно сделать отдельную таблицу "Заказы". Игрок будет формаировать очередной заказ - у которого есть id, прописано кол-во игровой валюты, статус "оплачено/не оплачено", и стоимость в рублях, или USD на момент заказа.

В ПС игрок уходит без цифр кол-ва игровой валюты - только с номером заказа и стоимостью в USD.

ПС подтверждает оплату этого id заказа, и сообщает, сколько фактически заплатили – напрямую вашему серверу, минуя клиента. Вы у себя проверяете, нормальна ли полученная сумма после вычета комиссий, и отмечаете заказ как "оплачен" и переводите заказвшему его на счет игровую валюту.

Comment: @sergiks спасибо. :)

Я сделал таким образом: клиент совершает платёж, я у себя ничего не сохраняю. Сервер получает от ПС подробности платежа, в том числе сколько фактически заплатили, и сервер выдаёт столько игровой валюты клиенту, за которую реально было уплачено. По сути у меня две конвертации. Сначала игровую валюту в USD, а потом конвертация после совершения платежа USD -> игровая валюта. :)